# VBA finding value and put it in specific column

Tags: vba, excel

Hope you you can help me here. I have a repetitive task every week, which I could do the same way every single time through Excel formulas, but I am looking for a more automated way of going about this.

[image: Data example]

What I want to achieve is to set-up a dynamic range that will look for multiple key words such as in this case "OA" & "SNC" and if it matches it will return the value in the column G & H respectively. At the same time it has to skip blank rows. What is the best way to go about this?

I figured it shouldn't be too hard, but I cannot figure it out.

[image: Expected results]

As per image above, I want to consolidate the charges per category (OA & SNC) in the designated columns ("G" & "H") on row level.

Comment: So, what are your expected results for "OA"? 7 or 300 ?

Comment: 300. but to clarify I am trying to get it as a single value per row i.e. cell G2 would be "50" whilst G4 would be "blank" if that makes any sense. I would need the data to be on row level, as each line is a single shipment that belong to different customers.

Comment: So, could you consider re-structuring your data? A column for OA and a separate column for SNC would make this much easier...

Comment: well, the problem is the data is provided in a fixed template by Fedex..., so unfortunately not much that I can do there re-structuring wise. the files that are provided by them don't put these charged in a fixed column, but in a different column each time... which makes this a very painful manual process so far with IF formulas.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt can you add to question expected results for a few lines please?

Comment: So the data could be in D:G instead of B:E?  Are the headings always 1, 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: @Flow when you say dynamic range, could this be both in terms of rows and columns or just rows? I.e. will the range always be columns B to E or could they be B to Z? Also is the value for OA and SNC always the same (50 and 20 repsectively)?

Comment: I just added a few lines & image of what I want to achieve. @MarkFitzgerald - yes that's correct. headings are always the same, but data might be in different columns.

Comment: @Matt_Roberts applies to both rows and columns. the amounts vary per time, in this particular example these are the same.

Comment: Are *OA* and *SNC* the only values you need to count? Are headings always at first row?

Comment: Do you want VBA code to enter formulas or result values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My approach to the task

Procedure finds data range, loops through it's values, adding unique values to the dictionary with sum for specific row and then loads all these values along with sums per row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountStuff()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lColumn As Long, lRow As Long, lColTotal As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngData As Range, iCell As Range
    Dim dictVal As Object
    Dim vArr(), vArrSub(), vArrEmpt()
    
    'Your workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Set wb = Workbooks("Workbook1")
    
    'Your worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Number of the first data range column
    lColumn = ws.Rows(1).Find("1", , xlValues, xlWhole).Column
    'Number of the last row of data range
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, lColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    'Total number of data range columns
    lColTotal = ws.Cells(1, lColumn).End(xlToRight).Column - lColumn + 1
    'Data range itself
    Set rngData = ws.Cells(1, lColumn).Resize(lRow, lColTotal)
    'Creating a dictionary
    Set dictVal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'Data values -> array
    vArr = rngData.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngData.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                       rngData.Columns.Count).Value
    'Empty array
    ReDim vArrEmpt(1 To UBound(vArr, 1))
    'Loop through all values
    For i = LBound(vArr, 1) To UBound(vArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2)
            'Value is not numeric and is not in dictionary
            If Not IsNumeric(vArr(i, j)) And _
                    Not dictVal.Exists(vArr(i, j)) Then
                'Add value to dictionary
                dictVal.Add vArr(i, j), vArrEmpt
                vArrSub = dictVal(vArr(i, j))
                vArrSub(i) = vArr(i, j - 1)
                dictVal(vArr(i, j)) = vArrSub
            'Value is not numeric but already exists
            ElseIf dictVal.Exists(vArr(i, j)) Then
                vArrSub = dictVal(vArr(i, j))
                vArrSub(i) = vArrSub(i) + vArr(i, j - 1)
                dictVal(vArr(i, j)) = vArrSub
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    'Define new range for results
    Set rngData = ws.Cells(1, lColumn + lColTotal - 1). _
        Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, dictVal.Count)
    'Load results
    rngData.Value = dictVal.Keys
    For Each iCell In rngData.Cells
        iCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow - 1).Value _
            = Application.Transpose(dictVal(iCell.Value))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had one question though, what does this specific part: "vArrSub(i) = vArr(i, j - 1)" do?

Comment: `vArrSub` is one-dimensinal array of all SUMs per row (`i` is a number of row), `vArr` is whole data array. It just overwrites SUM number for this row with current SUM of this particular key word on this row. I'm not sure how to explain ^^'

Answer (score 1):

I've used a simple custom function, possibly overkill as this could be done with worksheet formulae, but given that your ranges can vary in either direction...

```
Function altsum(r As Range, v As Variant) As Variant

Dim c As Long

For c = 2 To r.Columns.Count Step 2
    If r.Cells(c) = v Then altsum = altsum + r.Cells(c - 1)
Next c

If altsum = 0 Then altsum = vbNullString

End Function
```

Example below, copy and formula in F2 across and down (or apply it one go with another bit of code).

[image]